# dropwizard max json body size

Tags: java, json, jetty, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard for REST Services and would like to limit maximum body (json) size for POST request.

I tried setting `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize` to 1 but that doesn't limit body size.

If there any other way to set the limit ?

Comment: Dropwizard is using [io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jetty/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jetty/MutableServletContextHandler.java). You can call **ContextHandler.setMaxFormContentSize(int maxSize);** on instances of this object. However I haven't checked how you can get to **MutableServletContextHandler** objects.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I also have the same issue. Also where did u set org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize? Is it in the yml file or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `MutableServletContextHandler` from the DropWizard `environment`:

```
environment.getApplicationContext().setMaxFormContentSize(1024);
```

However, the `MaxFormContentSize` only applies to form encoded requests.

To limit the size of the request body for a POST request, you can check the content length when you handle the request in your Resource class:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
public Response test(@Context final HttpServletRequest request) {
    int contentLength = request.getContentLength();
    if (contentLength == -1 || contentLength > MAX_REQUEST_SIZE) {
        // fail the request
    }       
    // do work
}
```